# Django modelform remove "required" attribute based on other field choice

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I have ModelForm with several fields. Some of fields are required, some not. Also I have Select field with different choices, and I want to make some of fields "required" or not based on this Select field choice.

I tried in clean() method of Form

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    some_field = cleaned_data.get("some_field")
    if some_field == 'some_value':
          self.fields['other_field'].required = False
    return cleaned_data
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the Django documentation on [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).  The standard practice would be to perform the following handling instead:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    some_field = cleaned_data.get("some_field")
    if some_field == 'some_value':
          # 'other_field' is conditionally required.
          if not cleaned_data['other_field']:
              raise forms.ValidationError("'Other_field' is required.")
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: I need to do a similar validation (Django 1.4) but the field I'm testing is read only so I don't have it in my cleaned_data (btw - I'm doing it in the admin). Any idea how to acess the value of this read only field? 10x

Comment: Found the solution - form.instance holds all the relevant data, and the modified data is included in form.changed_data

Comment: Although this sounds like the right approach, I think the logic of checking `some_field == some_value` could be duplicated in the view. Not sure what's the right way? Live with redundancy or move this validation to view?

Comment: @buffer: I don't see why the view would need to repeat the validation logic since the form already does it.  If the view has a similar check (in order to determine whether to use `other_field` or not), that can't be avoided in a two-pass system (1 pass for validation, 1 pass for consumption) AFAICT.  If you prefer, you can move that logic to the view only, but then you may repeat the same logic for multiple views that use the same form.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea but the problem is that the individual field validations have already run before the form clean. You have a couple options. You could make the field not required and handle the logic of when it is required in your `form.clean`. Or you could leave the field as required and remove the validation errors it might raise in the clean.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    some_field = cleaned_data.get("some_field")
    if some_field == 'some_value':
          if 'other_field' in self.errors:
              del self.errors['other_field']
              cleaned_data['other_field'] = None
    return cleaned_data
```

This has some problems in that it removes *all* errors, not just missing/required errors. There is also a problem with the `cleaned_data`. You now have a required field which isn't in the cleaned_data which is why I've added it as `None`. The rest of your application will have to handle this case. It might seem odd to have a required field which doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to print error message for required field in common way, you can do this:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(PasswordChangeForm, self).clean()
    token = cleaned_data.get('token')
    old_password = cleaned_data.get('old_password')
    if not token and not old_password:
        self._errors['old_password'] = self.error_class([self.fields['old_password'].error_messages['required']])
```

Comment: This answer is really, really useful ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution.
You can use your condition before form.is_valid() and include your change in your field.

```
if form.data['tid_id'] is None: # my condition
    form.fields['prs_razonsocial'].required = True
    form.fields['prs_nombres'].required = False
    form.fields['prs_apellidos'].required = False
if form.is_valid():
...
```