# admin django field exclude dropdown

Tags: python, django, django-admin, field, models

I have the following model

```
class Consultation(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField('Id', primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField('date')
    services = models.CharField('services', choices=SERVICES, max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField('weight', decimal_places=1, max_digits=10)
    size = models.DecimalField('size', decimal_places=1, max_digits=10)
    imc = models.DecimalField('size', decimal_places=1, max_digits=10)
```

I have the field "service", in which three options ('a', 'b', 'c') are deployed.

my question is: is it possible that when you create a record of this model (add), selecting for example the option "a" field "service", the 'imc' field is excluded?

I tested with the method "get_form" but does not work when I want to add a record only when already registered.

thanks for the help!

Comment: By excluded here, do you mean hidden from UI or just the backend ?

Comment: as I can understand your question should be in the UI because that is where the user sees the form to add a new record.

My idea is that when selecting an option some fields are excluded because it is not always necessary to display all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the exclude validations in the clean method of your **Consultation** class. Check the below link and you can implement a similar validation like the following

```
if services == 'a':
    self.fields['imc'].required = False
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7093995/4757102

Comment: I need to exclude the field. you sent is required to do the field ... something completely different to my question (-1)